# how to iterate over files in python and export several output files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file

I have a code and I want to put it in a for loop. I want to input some data stored as files into my code and based on the each input, generate outputs automatically. At the moment, my code is only working for one input file and consequently gives one output. My input file is named as `model000.msh`, but the fact is that I have a series of these input files with the names `model000.msh`, `model001.msh`, and so on. In the code I am doing some calculation on the imported file and finally compare it to a numpy array (`my_data`) that is generated by another numpy array (`ID`) having one column and thousands of rows. `ID` array is the second variable which I want to iterate over. `ID` is making `my_data` through a `np.concatenate` function. I want to use each column of `ID` to make `my_data` (`my_data=np.concatenate((ID[:,iterator], gr), axis =1)`). So, I want to iterate over several files, then extract arrays from each file (`extracted`), then follow the loop with generating `my_data` from each column of `ID` and do calculations on `my_data` and `extracted` and finally export results of each iteration with a dynamic naming method (`changed_000`, `changed_001` and so on). This is my code fo one single input and one single `my_data` array (made by an `ID` that has only one column), but I want to change iterate over several input files and several `my_data` arrays and finally several outputs:

```
from itertools import islice
with open('model000.msh') as lines:
        nodes = np.genfromtxt(islice(lines, 0, 1000))
with open('model000.msh', "r") as f:
    saved_lines = np.array([line.split() for line in f if len(line.split()) == 9])
saved_lines[saved_lines == ''] = 0.0
elem = saved_lines.astype(np.int)
# following lines extract some data from my file
extracted=np.c_[elem[:,:-4], nodes[elem[:,-4]-1, 1:], nodes[elem[:,-3]-1, 1:],nodes[elem[:,-2]-1, 1:], nodes[elem[:,-1]-1, 1:]]
…
extracted =np.concatenate((extracted, avs), axis =1) # each input file ('model000.msh') will make this numpy array
# another data set, stored as a numpy array is compared to the data extracted from the file
ID= np.array [[… ..., …, …]] # now, it is has one column, but it should have several columns and each iteration, one column will make a my_data array
my_data=np.concatenate((ID, gr), axis =1) # I think it should be something like my_data=np.concatenate((ID[:,iterator], gr), axis =1)
from scipy.spatial import distance
distances=distance.cdist(extracted [:,17:20],my_data[:,1:4])
ind_min_dis=np.argmin(distances, axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
z=np.array([])
for i in ind_min_dis:
    u=my_data[i,0]
    z=np.array([np.append(z,u)]).reshape(-1,1)
final_merged=np.concatenate((extracted,z), axis =1)
new_vol=final_merged[:,-1].reshape(-1,1)
new_elements=np.concatenate((elements,new_vol), axis =1)
new_elements[:,[4,-1]] = new_elements[:,[-1,4]]
# The next block is output block
chunk_size = 3
buffer = ""
i = 0
relavent_line = 0
with open('changed_00', 'a') as fout:
    with open('model000.msh', 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            if len(line.split()) == 9:
                aux_string = ' '.join([str(num) for num in new_elements[relavent_line]])
                buffer += '%s\n' % aux_string
                relavent_line += 1
            else:
                buffer += line 
            i+=1
            if i == chunk_size:
                fout.write(buffer)
                i=0
                buffer = ""
    if buffer:
        fout.write(buffer)
        i=0
        buffer = ""
```

I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure about your question. But it seems like you are asking for something like:

```py
for idx in range(10):
    with open('changed_{:0>2d}'.format(idx), 'a') as fout:
        with open('model0{:0>2d}.msh'.format(idx), 'r') as fin:
            #read something from fin...
            #calculate something...
            #write something to fout...
```

If so, you could search for str.format() for more details.

Comment: Dear @Dipsy, Thanks for your feedback. I want to input several files (`model000.msh` and so on), extract some data (`extracted`). Again make an array (`my_data`) from a bigger one (`ID`). Compare `my_data` with `extracted` and export a file (`changed_00`). My code is doning it for a single input and ecports one output, but I want to iterate over several input files and then export also several files.

Comment: I think my answer could solve your problem if you do exactly the same actions for every input file.

Comment: Dear @Dipsy, I do appreciate it. Can you please elaborate it a littile bit more. How can I iterate over several input files and also generate several `my_data` from each column of `ID`? Thank you for devoting time. I am new with python and it is a little bit tough for me to solve such issues.

Comment: As for how to iterate over several input files, I've told you using `for` and `str.format()` to open different input files.
As for your `data` and `ID`(I'm sorry that I feel confused about this), I think your should simplify your question and create a new question page. We are not supposed to read your whole code and tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Dear @Dipsy, I do appreciate your informative hints. I try to solve it using your hints and helps.